# What is Implied Shares Outstanding in Yahoo Finance Statistics

Tags: yahoo-finance, statistics

It seem that [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/key-statistics?p=TSLA) has recently  included a new (?) field they call `Implied Shares Outstanding`. However, I cannot find the exact definition of this term anywhere. The only thing I can find is *Implied Value Per Share*, which is better known as *earnings per share*, but I don't think that is what they mean.

[image]

Q: *So what is the meaning of `Implied Shares Outstanding` (in Yahoo Finance's Statistics)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Footnote 6 explains what that means:

> 6 Implied Shares Outstanding of common equity, assuming the conversion of all convertible subsidiary equity into common.

There could be shares of subsidiaries of TSLA (probably through acquisition) that are *convertible* to TSLA shares. The Implied Shares Outstanding shows you how many shares outstanding TSLA *would* have if all of those shares were to be converted to TSLA stock.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading that, but it didn't make any sense at the time. Now it does.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with Class A and Class B shares. Class A is usually Shares outstanding, combining both A and B gives you implied

Comment: how should an investor think about it then? It can make the market cap look significantly different

Comment: For Yahoo Finance they use the implied shares outstanding to calculate the market cap. Implied shares outstanding should be a more accurate description for trading and investing purposes since there's nothing about Class B shares that can't also be traded or sold